# Library issues in perl scripts running on a remote drive

Tags: perl, dll

I am trying to run a script on a cluster using Microsoft HPC. As it stands I have my script (and the other necessary files) in a folder on a network drive (V:). I execute the script using a batch file which connects the computer on the cluster to /foo using the Net Use command (Net Use Z:)

When I try to execute the script I get a bunch of errors like this:

```
Can't load 'Z:/lib/auto/IO/IO.dll' for module IO: load_file:The specified module could not be found at C:/perl/perl/lib/XSLoader.pm line 71.
 at Z:/lib/IO.pm line 11
Compilation failed in require at Z:/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 266.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Z:/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 266.
Compilation failed in require at Z:/lib/IO/Seekable.pm line 101.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Z:/lib/IO/Seekable.pm line 101.
Compilation failed in require at Z:/lib/IO/File.pm line 133.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Z:/lib/IO/File.pm line 133.
Compilation failed in require at Z:/lib/FileHandle.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at Z:/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/OLEwriter.pm line 18.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Z:/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/OLEwriter.pm line 18.
Compilation failed in require at Z:/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Workbook.pm line 18.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Z:/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Workbook.pm line 18.
Compilation failed in require at Z:/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm line 17.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Z:/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm line 17.
Compilation failed in require at foo.pl line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at foo.pl line 9.
```

This script runs fine when I run it locally. My objective is to get it running remotely on the HPC cluster.

I have been trying to get my head around adding new and local library locations, but I find a lot of the explanations available around the web to be a little arcane for my abilities. In my head it should be sufficient to copy my existing /lib folder into my remote drive (Z:) and then use the 'use lib 'Z:\lib;' in my code, but that doesn't work. I am assuming there are aspects of how scripts interact with libraries that I don't understand currently.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you executing perl on the local machine? The one that has Z:? So you're doing something like `C:\perl\bin\perl.exe V:\source\prog.pl`? I'm wondering if the Perl program can see the drive letter. Run a test program from the same folder that checks, something like `print "OK" if -f 'Z:\lib\auto\IO\IO.dll'` and work from there. Also check the contents of `@INC`. If you're running perl from a remote machine then you need to do your `net use` from there first as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The code will run locally, it's when I try to run it on a remote machine that I hit problems. The Z: drive is the folder on the remote drive which holds the script, and perl is executed there. I made a test script that prints out cwd and @INC and I get the following:

C:/perl/perl/site/lib
C:/perl/perl/vendor/lib
C:/perl/perl/lib
.
Z:\

So it can see Z:\; I am not sure whether merely copying the contents of C:/Perl/lib to Z:/lib and setting it as a library using use lib 'Z:\lib' is sufficient, it doesn't seem to work when I have tried.

Cheers.

Comment: I tried 'print "OK" if -f 'Z:\lib\auto\IO\IO.dll'' and it prints OK.

Comment: Hmm well if Perl is finding the file using `-f` but `use` can't see it then all I can think of is that the remote process may not have execute permission on that file. You are aware that uf you have `use My::Nice::Module`, Perl will expect to find `Z:\My\Nice\Module.pm`?

Answer (score 2):

I'll raise it to an answer! If you're running a perl process on a remote machine then the Z: drive won't necessarily be available. You need to run `net use` there first, or perhaps try using a full UNC path, like

```
use lib '\\\\COMPUTER\root\lib';
```

(Yes you do need four backslashes at the start to make two! But use single-quotes or it will be worse.)

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I do set net use in the batch file which executes the perl script: `net use Z: \\folder` then `call setperl` then `Z:` then `perl foo.pl` etc. I am not sure how I would form the whole path, since the script is farmed out to a cluster rather than a specific computer. I appreciate the help, sorry if I am proving a little dense here.

Comment: `net use` doesn't look like that. You want `net use Z: \\COMPUTER\folder`, after which `Z:\lib` corresponds to `\\COMPUTER\folder\lib`. What does `setperl` do?